# SQL Query Help - Select non null values for each ID (multiple rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery where each ID has multiple rows, many with Null values. I want to combine the rows to create a complete set.

Here is a sample set of data:

```
ID    Address      CreatedDate     City
1    1 1st Street      NULL     New York City
1      NULL          8/18/17      NULL
2      NULL          8/13/17     Boston
2    2 2nd Street    NULL         NULL
3    3 3rd Street    8/1/17      Los Angeles
3     NULL             NULL       NULL
3     NULL           8/7/17       NULL
```

Here is the expected Output:

```
ID    Address      CreatedDate     City
1    1 1st Street    8/18/17    New York City
2    2 2nd Street    8/13/17     Boston
3    3 3rd Street    8/1/17      Los Angeles
```

Honestly I'm not sure this is even possible, but any suggestions would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: Ok, and how you pick the values if there are more options? For example ID 3 and attribute CreatedDate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the column you want to be unique and use `max()` to get the results containing something for each `id`

```
select ID, max(Address), max(CreatedDate), max(City)
from your_table
group by ID
```

Comment: Amazing. So fast. So accurate <3

Answer (score 2):

aggregation is the key here.  assuming you want the max/min value for each group if multiple exist.  looking at the date column on ID 3 it's min.

```
SELECT ID
     , min(address) as Address
     , min(createdDate) as createdDate
     , min(city) as City
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As another possibility, you could solve this one using the function [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) available in the [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) version of BigQuery (highly recommended that you use standard).

As for the query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY_AGG(Address IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1) Address,
  ARRAY_AGG(CreatedDate IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1) CreatedDate,
  ARRAY_AGG(City IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1) City
from
  `your_table`
GROUP BY
  ID
```

You can test with simulated data:

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 1 ID, '1 1st Street1' Address, NULL CreatedDate, 'New York City' City UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, '8/18/17', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL, '8/13/17', 'Boston' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2 2nd Street', NULL, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '3 3rd Street', '8/1/17', 'Los Angeles' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL, '8/7/17', NULL
)

SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY_AGG(Address IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1) Address,
  ARRAY_AGG(CreatedDate IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1) CreatedDate,
  ARRAY_AGG(City IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1) City
from
  data
GROUP BY
  ID
ORDER BY
  ID
```

You may find that queries once exceeding resources will be processed in seconds just by using `ARRAY_AGG` properly.